# How do you make a button only send one input to a source while being pushed down and not send another one until the button is let go and repressed?

Tags: variables, button, arduino

In a basic variable and Button setup on an Arduino software, the idea is that if you press a button, you gain one on a variable. Theoretically, holding the button shouldn't cause the variable to increase more than one until the release and repressing of the button. However, I could not make this happen. How is this supposed to be done?

I tried using an else around a delay (because the adding one to a variable code was inside an "if" statement) so it would not delay unless the button and released and would not count multiple button inputs, but this resulted in a larger increase when a button was clicked rather than just a one increase.

```
const int buttonPin = 8;
int number = 0;
int numbertwo = 0;
int buttonState = 0;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (buttonState == LOW){
    numbertwo = ++number;
  delay(100);
}
```

(Can use any method to determine variable, like on an LCD)

As mentioned above, I expected the variable to only increase by one when a button is pressed and not to continue increasing until the button is released and re-pressed, but what actually happened was the variable kept increasing in value as the button was held.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the variable "number" increase by 1 per press. I think you are looking for something like this:

```
const int buttonPin = 8;
int number = 0;
int buttonState = 0;
void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}
void loop()
{
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (buttonState == LOW){
    ++number;

    // This loop is to make sure not to count up until button is released
    do {
      delay(5);
      buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
    } while (buttonState == LOW);
  }
}
```

If you don't like the loop based implementation, here's a state based implementation for you:

```
const int buttonPin = 8;
int number = 0;
int buttonState = 0;
int prevState = -1;
void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  prevState = -1;
}
void loop()
{
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (buttonState == LOW && prevState != buttonState){
    ++number;
    prevState = buttonState;
  }
  delay(5);
}
```

Comment: You will have to debounce that. Easiest add a little `delay(5);` anywhere in loop.